# Need to add a choose box for windows 8 mobile app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am new to windows mobile app development and I use Visual studio 2012 to develop windows 8 mobile apps.I need to add a drop down list..Default when the page loads it must show "select your option" and when clicked on it a list of items should drop down.How can we add such a item.
Note that combo box is not working in this visual studio..

Comment: Look what I found. http://www.dotnetgeekette.com/2013/05/how-to-create-simple-dropdown-in.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer..to add a list we have to install the new version of NUget package and download WPtoolkit for the visual studio.this is because windows 8 do not have a list box build in it.

after adding that u can add the list box like this